# Jboss shutdown with authentication

Tags: security, jboss5.x, shutdown

I use jboss-5.0.1.GA and I want to restrict access for shutdown.sh

In jmx-console-users.properties, I have

```
admin=<password>
```

In jmx-invoker-service.xml, I uncommented the interceptor

```
 <descriptors>
           <interceptors>
              <!-- Uncomment to require authenticated users-->
              <interceptor code="org.jboss.jmx.connector.invoker.AuthenticationInterceptor"
                 securityDomain="java:/jaas/jmx-console"/>

              <!-- Interceptor that deals with non-serializable results -->
              <interceptor code="org.jboss.jmx.connector.invoker.SerializableInterceptor"
                 policyClass="StripModelMBeanInfoPolicy"/>
           </interceptors>
        </descriptors>
```

I tried command

```
../jboss-5.0.1.GA/bin/shutdown.sh -u admin -p <password>
```

I got the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Failed to authenticate principal==admin, securityDomain=jmx-console
    at org.jboss.jmx.connector.invoker.AuthenticationInterceptor.invoke(AuthenticationInterceptor.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:90)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
    at org.jboss.invocation.jrmp.server.JRMPProxyFactory.invoke(JRMPProxyFactory.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668) ......
```

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is post is from a year and a half ago but I came across this as one of the first searches while researching the same problem.  For anyone who is having this problem it is due to an incorrect init script being shipped with JBoss 5.  Reference the bugzilla link https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=777710 which contains the file EAP_43_jboss_init_redhat.sh which throws the process a SIGTERM signal rather than calling the JBoss shutdown command.  For reference in case the bugzilla link is unavailable the init script is posted here as well.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# $Id: jboss_init_redhat.sh 71029 2008-03-19 21:58:46Z dbhole $
#
# JBoss Control Script
#
# To use this script run it as root - it will switch to the specified user
#
# Here is a little (and extremely primitive) startup/shutdown script
# for RedHat systems. It assumes that JBoss lives in /usr/local/jboss,
# it's run by user 'jboss' and JDK binaries are in /usr/local/jdk/bin.
# All this can be changed in the script itself. 
#
# Either modify this script for your requirements or just ensure that
# the following variables are set correctly before calling the script.

#define where jboss is - this is the directory containing directories log, bin, conf etc
JBOSS_HOME=${JBOSS_HOME:-"/usr/local/jboss"}

#define the user under which jboss will run, or use 'RUNASIS' to run as the current user
JBOSS_USER=${JBOSS_USER:-"jboss"}

#make sure java is in your path
JAVAPTH=${JAVAPTH:-"/usr/local/jdk/bin"}

#configuration to use, usually one of 'minimal', 'default', 'all', 'production'
JBOSS_CONF=${JBOSS_CONF:-"production"}

#if JBOSS_HOST specified, use -b to bind jboss services to that address
JBOSS_BIND_ADDR=${JBOSS_HOST:+"-b $JBOSS_HOST"}

#define the script to use to start jboss
JBOSSSH=${JBOSSSH:-"$JBOSS_HOME/bin/run.sh -c $JBOSS_CONF $JBOSS_BIND_ADDR"}

if [ "$JBOSS_USER" = "RUNASIS" ]; then
  SUBIT=""
else
  SUBIT="su - $JBOSS_USER -c "
fi

if [ -n "$JBOSS_CONSOLE" -a ! -d "$JBOSS_CONSOLE" ]; then
  # ensure the file exists
  touch $JBOSS_CONSOLE
  if [ ! -z "$SUBIT" ]; then
    chown $JBOSS_USER $JBOSS_CONSOLE
  fi 
fi

if [ -n "$JBOSS_CONSOLE" -a ! -f "$JBOSS_CONSOLE" ]; then
  echo "WARNING: location for saving console log invalid: $JBOSS_CONSOLE"
  echo "WARNING: ignoring it and using /dev/null"
  JBOSS_CONSOLE="/dev/null"
fi

#define what will be done with the console log
JBOSS_CONSOLE=${JBOSS_CONSOLE:-"/dev/null"}

JBOSS_CMD_START="cd $JBOSS_HOME/bin; $JBOSSSH"

if [ -z "`echo $PATH | grep $JAVAPTH`" ]; then
  export PATH=$PATH:$JAVAPTH
fi

if [ ! -d "$JBOSS_HOME" ]; then
  echo JBOSS_HOME does not exist as a valid directory : $JBOSS_HOME
  exit 1
fi

echo JBOSS_CMD_START = $JBOSS_CMD_START

function procrunning() {
   procid=0
   JBOSSSCRIPT=$(echo $JBOSSSH | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/\//\\\//g')
   for procid in `/sbin/pidof -x "$JBOSSSCRIPT"`; do
       ps -fp $procid | grep "${JBOSSSH% *}" > /dev/null && pid=$procid
   done
}


stop() {
    pid=0
    procrunning
    if [ $pid = '0' ]; then
        echo -n -e "\nNo JBossas is currently running\n"
        exit 1
    fi

    RETVAL=1

    # If process is still running

    # First, try to kill it nicely
    for id in `ps --ppid $pid | awk '{print $1}' | grep -v "^PID$"`; do
       if [ -z "$SUBIT" ]; then
           kill -15 $id
       else
           $SUBIT "kill -15 $id"
       fi
    done

    sleep=0
    while [ $sleep -lt 120 -a $RETVAL -eq 1 ]; do
        echo -n -e "\nwaiting for processes to stop";
        sleep 10
        sleep=`expr $sleep + 10`
        pid=0
        procrunning
        if [ $pid == '0' ]; then
            RETVAL=0
        fi
    done

    # Still not dead... kill it

    count=0
    pid=0
    procrunning

    if [ $RETVAL != 0 ] ; then
        echo -e "\nTimeout: Shutdown command was sent, but process is still running with PID $pid"
        exit 1
    fi

    echo
    exit 0
}

case "$1" in
start)
    cd $JBOSS_HOME/bin
    if [ -z "$SUBIT" ]; then
        eval $JBOSS_CMD_START >${JBOSS_CONSOLE} 2>&1 &
    else
        $SUBIT "$JBOSS_CMD_START >${JBOSS_CONSOLE} 2>&1 &" 
    fi
    ;;
stop)
    stop
    ;;
restart)
    $0 stop
    $0 start
    ;;
*)
    echo "usage: $0 (start|stop|restart|help)"
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem:

When execute the command:

```
../jboss-5.0.1.GA/bin/shutdown.sh -u admin -p <password>
```

It looks at jmx-invoker-service.xml for "securityDomain" and goes to login-config.xml to find the match.
`securityDomain="java:/jaas/jmx-console"/`

login-config.xml configuration looks like this:

```
<application-policy name="jmx-console">
<authentication>
  <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsersRolesLoginModule"
    flag="required">
    <module-option name="usersProperties">props/jmx-console-users.properties</module-option>
    <module-option name="rolesProperties">props/jmx-console-roles.properties</module-option>
    <module-option name="hashAlgorithm">MD5</module-option> 
    <module-option name="hashEncoding">base64</module-option>        
  </login-module>
</authentication>
```

Then it goes to jmx-console-users.properties to find defined username and passowrd.

```
admin=fGoYCzaJagqMAnh+6vsOTA==
```

the password in the property file is encrypted using MD5 (it's clear text is "password1").

The trick is the command I have to use clear text:

like: `../jboss-5.0.1.GA/bin/shutdown.sh -u admin -p password1`

But I put this command in a script with encrpt password

```
../jboss-5.0.1.GA/bin/shutdown.sh -u admin -p fGoYCzaJagqMAnh+6vsOTA==
```

Still have two questions:

1.Is there a way to use shutdown with encrypted password? I don't want to have a clear text password in my script. 
2.What's the options for encryption algorithm other than MD5? Any algorithm strong than MD5? Anyone can help on this?

Answer (score 0):

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/CryptoSpec.html#AppA

```
Message Digest Algorithms
The algorithm names in this section can be specified when generating an instance of MessageDigest. 

MD2: The MD2 message digest algorithm as defined in RFC 1319. 

MD5: The MD5 message digest algorithm as defined in RFC 1321. 

SHA-1: The Secure Hash Algorithm, as defined in Secure Hash Standard, 
       NIST FIPS 180-1. 

SHA-256, SHA-384, and SHA-512: New hash algorithms for which the draft Federal
Information Processing Standard 180-2, Secure Hash Standard (SHS) is now available.
SHA-256 is a 256-bit hash function intended to provide 128 bits of security against
collision attacks, while SHA-512 is a 512-bit hash function intended to provide 256
bits of security. A 384-bit hash may be obtained by truncating the SHA-512 output.
```

Answer (score 0):

echo -n [password] | openssl dgst -md5 -binary | openssl base64

Run above script to get encrypted password using md5.
Put that in jmx-console-users.properties and stopServer.sh